# How to compare two fileStat.mtime in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, date

See the code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = "e:/myfile.txt";

fs.stat(file, function(err, stat1) {
  console.log(stat1.mtime);
  fs.stat(file, function(err, stat2) {
    console.log(stat2.mtime);
    console.log(stat1.mtime == stat2.mtime);
    console.log(stat1.mtime === stat2.mtime);
  });
});
```

And the result:

```
Sun, 20 May 2012 15:47:15 GMT
Sun, 20 May 2012 15:47:15 GMT
false
false
```

I didn't change the file during execution. But you can see no matter `==` or `===`, they are not equal.

How to compare two `mtime` in nodejs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`==` on objects test if the objects are equal. However, `<` and `>` do the job propertly for Date objects, so you can simply use this function to compare the two objects:

```
function datesEqual(a, b) {
    return !(a > b || b > a);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `date.getTime()` to compare:

```
function datesEqual(a, b) {
    return a.getTime() === b.getTime();
}
```